# Android: Activity sliding over another one with swipe gesture

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe-gesture, activity-transition

I have two activities one with some data and the second one, semitrasparent with some buttons on it.
I want the second activity slide over the first one after the swipe gesture.

I've already read about ViewPager and it's not what I am looking for. I want the first activity still being visible over the semitrasparent second one.

I am looking for any suggestions how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Literally not possible.

The entire point of an Activity is that it fills the ENTIRE screen, and there are never 2 of them shown at the same time, ever.

So you can't swipe to "semi" open one with a slide animation.

To do that, you'll have to use 1 Activity, and multiple Fragments.

Comment: Okey I understand, but still I dont know to to achive the type of transition I was talking about.